# Cache mapping problem

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-management, cpu-cache

Okay.I have problem about cache mapping. Here is the problem .

Memory size is 1 MB 
Byte addresable  
Cache block size is 16 Bytes. 
Cache size is 64kb

Since memory is 1 mb=2**20 Bytes.
 
So we need 20 bits for the one single address . 
Since it is byte addressable and each block size is 16 bytes we need for 4 bits the offset 
 
and for the index 64 KB/16 bytes is equal to 2 to the power 12
so we need 12 bits for the index
So remain part goes to the tag and which is 20-(12+4) = 4 bits.

After that I have given address which is 32 bit long in hexadecimal. For example
0X66349068

My question is how to find the tag,index and offset from the above address?

Comment: Under normal circumstances we would convert the hexadecimal number to binary and then pick out the tag, index and offset. If your physical memory address is 20 bit long, how are you going to have a 32 bit address in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.I had the same idea.But the question was given as above

Comment: If the question is not from a standard source then it's pointless to waste time on trivial mistakes.

Comment: It was question from a university paper.I thought that question is wrong.But cant say it surely

Comment: Anyone have idea whether the question is correct or not?